# Modifying env:path and run a exe file on Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to build a powershell script with a command-line menu that calls to other powershell scripts. This is running from a script.bat to avoid executionPolicy issues.

```
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File  scripts\install-script.ps1
```

Mostly all the menu options are working but i have problems with one of them.

I needs to run a sample.exe file, but previously I need to run another OpenVino "setupvars.bat" script that sets some environment variables and add some routes to the env:path among other checkings.

If i do this manually on a CMD window works fine:

```
call "C:\Program Files(x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\bin\setupvars.bat" 
.\sample_***.exe
```

On the script i'm trying to do something like this:

```
        '1' {
               cls 
               Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino\bin\setupvars.bat" *>&1 | Out-Null
               Start-Process "sample_interactive_mask.exe"
         } 'e' { 
                return 
           }  
     } 
     pause
```

But it is not working showing errors of some of the dependencies needed can not be founded.

I'm guessing that env variable and path routes added are done on one window and the sample.exe is executed on a different environment without this variables properly set.

Any way to achieve the final result?

Comment: Have a look at my response to another question the other day, here you have instructions how to update the env:path. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63144984/certain-commands-like-iisreset-and-robocopy-have-stopped-working-in-powershell-v/63153284?noredirect=1#comment111686782_63153284

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a similar issue with VisualStudio. The only workaround I have found is to convert the setupvars.bat in powershell.

It's not so complicated to do, for example this section from my **vcvarsall.bat** :

```
:x86
echo Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 x86 tools.
set VCINSTALLDIR=%~dp0VC\
set WindowsSdkDir=%~dp0WinSDK\
if not exist "%VCINSTALLDIR%bin\cl.exe" goto missing
set PATH=%VCINSTALLDIR%Bin;%WindowsSdkDir%Bin;%PATH%
set INCLUDE=%VCINSTALLDIR%Include;%WindowsSdkDir%Include;%INCLUDE%
set LIB=%VCINSTALLDIR%Lib;%WindowsSdkDir%Lib;%LIB%
set LIBPATH=%VCINSTALLDIR%Lib;%WindowsSdkDir%Lib;%LIBPATH%
goto :eof
```

can be translated to :

```
"Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 x86 tools."
$PathToDir = "C:\Users\toto\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0"

$VCINSTALLDIR  = "$PathToDir\VC"
$WindowsSdkDir = "$PathToDir\WinSDK"

$env:PATH    = "$VCINSTALLDIR\Bin;$WindowsSdkDir\Bin;$env:PATH"
$env:INCLUDE = "$VCINSTALLDIR\Include;$WindowsSdkDir\Include;$env:INCLUDE"
$env:LIB     = "$VCINSTALLDIR\Lib;$WindowsSdkDir\Lib;$env:LIB"
$env:LIBPATH = "$VCINSTALLDIR\Lib;$WindowsSdkDir\Lib;$env:LIBPATH"
```